# How do I check whether these expressions are identical?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-test

Consider:

```
R0n = (β Λ (-1 + ξ) (-1 +  ρ))/((α + γ + θ + μ) (μ + ξ +  ρ));
xn = σ1^2 + m;
yn = 2 (μ + ρ + ξ) - σ1^2 - m;
k1 = 1/(μ + α + θ + γ);
k2 = Sqrt[R0n]/η;
```

Then I wish to check whether the following are identical:

```
(k1 β (1 - ρ) (1 - ξ)/ k2) (xn Λ^2/((μ + ρ + ξ)^2 yn))^(1/2)
```

and

```
η ((R0n xn)/yn)^(1/2)
```

I tried `FullSimplify` but it is still a mess and didn't make things clearer.

Edit:

Applying `FullSimplify` to the first expression, we get:

```
 (β η (-1 + ξ) (-1 + ρ) Sqrt[-((Λ^2 \
(m + σ1^2))/((μ + ξ + ρ)^2 (m - 
     2 (μ + ξ + ρ) + σ1^2)))])/Sqrt[(β \
Λ (α + γ + θ + μ) (-1 + \
ξ) (-1 + ρ))/(μ + ξ + ρ)]
```

Applying it to the second:

```
η Sqrt[-((β Λ (-1 + ξ) (-1 + ρ) (m \
+ σ1^2))/((α + γ + θ + μ) (μ + \
ξ + ρ) (m - 2 (μ + ξ + ρ) + σ1^2)))]
```

Now shifting `β (-1 + ξ) (-1 + ρ)` into the radical, and applying `Fullsimplify` to inside of the radical, we get:

```
-((β Λ (-1 + ξ) (-1 + ρ) (m + \
σ1^2))/((α + γ + θ + μ) (μ + \
ξ + ρ) (m - 2 (μ + ξ + ρ) + σ1^2)))
```

which is identical to the inside of the radical of the second expression.

Comment: I did get something, I'm pretty certain they're identical but I hope someone can confirm.

Comment: Probably you can [edit] the question to include the details behind *"I did get something"*.  There are trivial cases for which these are equal, like $\eta = 0$, but I don't see that been true in general.

Comment: all constants are positive. does that help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

R0n = (β Λ (-1 + ξ) (-1 + ρ))/((α + \
γ + θ + μ) (μ + ξ + ρ));
xn = σ1^2 + m;
yn = 2 (μ + ρ + ξ) - σ1^2 - m;
k1 = 1/(μ + α + θ + γ);
k2 = Sqrt[R0n]/η;

var = {m, α, β, γ, η, θ, Λ, μ, ξ, ρ, σ1};
```

You need to specify some assumptions or constraints on the variables. For example,

```
Assuming[Element[var, PositiveReals] && ρ > 1 && ξ > 1,
 (k1 β (1 - ρ) (1 - ξ)/
       k2) (xn Λ^2/((μ + ρ + ξ)^2 yn))^(1/
       2) == η ((R0n xn)/yn)^(1/2) // FullSimplify]

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** Or, another example

```
Assuming[
 Element[var, PositiveReals] && 0 < ξ < 1 && 0 < ρ < 1, 
    (k1 β (1 - ρ) (1 - ξ)/
       k2) (xn Λ^2/((μ + ρ + ξ)^2 yn))^(1/
       2) == η ((R0n xn)/yn)^(1/2) // FullSimplify]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Hmm, why did you assume $\rho$ and $\xi$ were $>1$? the expression should technically read $\beta (1-\rho)(1-\xi)$ with $0\leq \rho, \xi \leq1$

Comment: To insure that `Sqrt[R0n]` isn't complex.

Comment: If there are known constraints you should include that information in the question. And Mathematica generally needs to be provided that information as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Monte Carlo way to verify this.

You may choose random positive reals for the parameters and check if the outcome is true. You then repeat this many times. And if you always get True the probability of the claim to be true goes towards 1:

```
AllTrue[Table[
  e1 == e2 /. 
   Thread[{\[Mu], \[Xi], \[Rho] , m, \[Sigma]1, k1, k2, xn, 
      yn, \[CapitalLambda]} ->  RandomReal[{0, 100}, 10]], 100], # &]

(* True *)
```